# LINQPad - can't understand the query generated

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, linqpad

I typed the following LINQ in LINQPad and using the connection to my database (SQL Server 2005) using dbcontext.

```
from j in Jobs
where j.dValuationDate.HasValue && j.dValuationDate.Value > EntityFunctions.AddDays(DateTime.Now, -7).Value &&
j.dValuationDate.Value < EntityFunctions.AddHours(DateTime.Now, -1).Value &&
j.bXMLServiceProviderID.HasValue && j.bXMLServiceProviderID.Value == 1 &&
!ValuationDelays.Any(x => x.iJobID == j.iJobID && x.iStatusID == 5)
select j.iJobID
```

Jobs and ValuationDelays are tables in my database linked by iJobId column.

The SQL generated by LINQPad is:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[iDelayID] AS [iDelayID], 
[Extent1].[iJobID] AS [iJobID], 
[Extent1].[sReasonforDelay] AS [sReasonforDelay], 
[Extent1].[dDateTime] AS [dDateTime], 
[Extent1].[iStaffID] AS [iStaffID], 
[Extent1].[iStatusID] AS [iStatusID], 
[Extent1].[dSentDate] AS [dSentDate], 
[Extent1].[yValExDelayReasonID] AS [yValExDelayReasonID], 
[Extent1].[dDelayedUntilDate] AS [dDelayedUntilDate], 
[Extent1].[dValuationDate] AS [dValuationDate], 
[Extent1].[valexActionUpdateId] AS [valexActionUpdateId], 
[Extent1].[valexAppointmentReasonId] AS [valexAppointmentReasonId]
FROM [dbo].[ValuationDelays] AS [Extent1]
```

Note there is no where clause. I can't understand why LINQPad will generate such a query. What am I doing wrong?

The query runs fine and returning expected results in C# code when I debug in VS 2010.

Comment: The select statement (in SQL) is all messed up to. It should only select `iJobID`...

Comment: opun further inspection, the two statements doesn't match up at all. The select is wrong, and the `From` is not the same table! Try running your Linq query again, and make sure it updates the SQL result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got `!ValuationDelays` in stead of `!j.ValuationDelays`.

It looks like this causes EF to load all `ValuationDelay`s from the database and handle the whole statement in memory. I can't explain why there is no query for the predicates on the `Job` record, but at least you've got something to correct now.

Comment: ValuationDelays is not part of jobs tables. Its a separate table just like jobs.

What I am trying to do here is write a not EXISTS clause.

_italic_not EXISTS (select 1 from valuationdelays where iJobID=j.iJobID AND iStatusID=5)_italic_

Comment: Sorry, I see what you saying here. Instead of referring "ValuationDelays" directly, I should refer to it via jobs foreign key (j.ValuationDelays). I will check and accept the answer or reply.

Comment: Okay its working this way. I also don't need x.iJobId == j.iJobId now.

The shortened version is:
`from j in Jobs
where j.dValuationDate.HasValue && j.dValuationDate.Value > EntityFunctions.AddDays(DateTime.Now, -7).Value &&
j.dValuationDate.Value < EntityFunctions.AddHours(DateTime.Now, -1).Value &&
j.bXMLServiceProviderID.HasValue && j.bXMLServiceProviderID.Value == 1 &&
!j.ValuationDelays.Any(x => x.iStatusID == 5)
select j.iJobID`